# SQL - Hibernate unexpected token

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I run the query below directly in the Mysql database and it works as expected:

```
select lu.* from LocationUpdate lu inner join (select imsi,MAX(date) as maxdate from LocationUpdate group by imsi) grouplu on lu.imsi = grouplu.imsi and lu.date = grouplu.maxdate
```

In HQL I've just changed `lu.*` to `lu` but I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 114 [select lu from com.truphone.simmanager.simcard.service.impl.entities.locationupdate.LocationUpdate lu inner join (select imsi,MAX(date) as maxdate from com.truphone.simmanager.simcard.service.impl.entities.locationupdate.LocationUpdate group by imsi) grouplu on lu.imsi = grouplu.imsi and lu.date = grouplu.maxdate]
```

Anyone knows what I'm missing?

Comment: I think lu must be replaced with LocationUpdate as HQL will treat as enity to it .Just replace `select lu from` to `select LocationUpdate  from` and try again

Comment: That's not the solution. It can be done but Hibernate can convert LocationUpdate to lu. I've that in other scenarios. Thanks for trying help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without select statement

"from LocationUpdate lu inner join (select imsi,MAX(date) as maxdate from LocationUpdate group by imsi) grouplu on lu.imsi = grouplu.imsi and lu.date = grouplu.maxdate"